# Facebook embedded posts

Tags: javascript, facebook, asynchronous

I have a simple webpage for testing facebook embedded posts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/10151471074398553" data-width="500"></div>

        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=608515702536335";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

This code comes directly from the [facebook developer page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/). If I open chrome dev tools and inspect my page I can see that everything loads fine:

[image]

Fortunatly the embedded post only shows up if I copy the code from the [link](http://connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=608515702536335) and paste it directly into my console.

What am I doing wrong? Everything seems to be loaded fine..?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error, I was testing in IE and it was working there. The error was because I had a chrome extension installed 'facebook-disconnect'. I removed it and now it's working just fine..